# How to accept a file upload using Protobuf

Tags: reactjs, go, protocol-buffers

Using protobuf to handle my request generation, but struggling to understand how I can upload a file and access it then upload to s3.

Here is my message:

```
  message FileRequest {
    bytes file_content = 1;
  }
```

In react, on the file input being changed:

```
  const handleFile = (file: File) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = (e) => {
      const result = e.target?.result as ArrayBuffer;
      const fileContent = new Uint8Array(result);
      const newFileRequest: FileRequest = {
        file_content: fileContent,
      };

      addImage(newFileRequest).then(() => {
        alert("finished");
      });
    };

    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
  };
```

Am I approaching this the wrong way? Upon trying to parse the request on the backend, getting:

`invalid value for bytes type: {`

It fails on:

````
            var rawJson json.RawMessage
            if err := json.NewDecoder(reader).Decode(&rawJson); err != nil {
                if errors.Cause(err) == io.ErrUnexpectedEOF || errors.Cause(err) == io.EOF {
                    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusBadRequest)
                    return
                }

                panic(errors.Wrapf(err, "decode json failed from %s", r.Method))
            }

            unmarshaller := protojson.UnmarshalOptions{DiscardUnknown: true}
            err := unmarshaller.Unmarshal(rawJson, message)
            if err != nil {
                panic(errors.Wrapf(err, "unmarshal json failed from %s", r.Method))
            }
    ```
````

Comment: Do you want to keep frontend part sending the file as buffer? Or are you ok with changing it to send file as form-data